# Syntax In Directive

Tags: angularjs

I followed this YouTube on Directives

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r5QvzjjKDc

and it was very good, imo.  Got through following along successfully right up until the very end (link).  The debugger is telling me

**TypeError: element.click is not a function**

I've looked at this seven ways to Sunday and I'm just not seeing where it's not matching what he's got.  Is the syntax error jumping out at you?

Thanks.

```
    angular
     .module('app.directives.contactCard', [])
     .directive('contactCard', function() {
return {
    /* choices are E-Element, A-Attribute, or C */
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        friend: '=',
        title: '=',

    },
    replace: true,      
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "contactCard.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.click(function() {
            alert('click');
        });
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.friend);
    }
}
 })
```

Comment: If possible, please include the HTML template you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty good, just a slight problem with the `element` syntax. The error is indicating there is no such function (i.e. `click()`) on `element`.

Try using the following, which uses `bind`:

```
element.bind('click', function() {
   alert('click');
})
```

I replicated your directive here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SX0zwYipydVvo6EMVfzE

Comment: Sweet.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @ebick No problem. If it solved your issue, feel free to accept the answer; this way if other folks have a similar issue they'll be able to glean the solution a bit quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Overall you're on the right track, but the hypothetical click function like that is more reminiscent of the jQuery way of doing things than the Angular way. Typically, if it feels like you're trying to manipulate the features of the DOM through JS, you're thinking in jQuery instead of Angular. I realize that the tutorial utilized it, but it somewhat defeats the purpose of Angular, and I think hides a lot of its real power.

Common conventions for click-functions would be to assign a function to `$scope` in the directive's controller (or to the directive itself), then refer to it with `ng-click` in the directive's template.

If you can update your question to include the template, I can give a more specific example. I expect it'll be extremely succinct.